# Solution $u(x,t)$ of Heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

$$\begin{cases}
u_t = u_{xx}, &x \in \mathbb{R},\quad t> 0\\
u(x,0) = e^{-x^2}\sin x, &x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}$$

I used the general formula of the heat equation in $\mathbb{R}$, but I can not come up with an explicit solution.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? We can point you where you were wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> The solution was already given by
> [@amathstudent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2300681/85343). The integral evaluation requires the "complete the square" in the following evaluation:

\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} & \equiv 
{1 \over \root{4\pi t}}\,\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\,{\pars{x - y}^{2} \over 4t} - y^{2} + \ic y}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \root{4\pi t}}\,\exp\pars{-\,{x^{2} + t \over 1 + 4t}}\,
\Im\braces{\exp\pars{\ic x \over 1 + 4t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\bracks{1 + {1 \over 4t}}\bracks{y - \tilde{y}}^{2}}\,\dd y}
\end{align}

> where $\ds{\tilde{y} \equiv {x + 2\ic t \over 1 + 4t}}$

\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} & =
{1 \over \root{4\pi t}}\,\exp\pars{-\,{x^{2} + t \over 1 + 4t}}\,
\Im\braces{\exp\pars{\ic x \over 1 + 4t}
\int_{-\infty - \tilde{y}}^{\infty - \tilde{y}}
\exp\pars{-\bracks{1 + {1 \over 4t}}y^{2}}\,\dd y}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \root{4\pi t}}\,\exp\pars{-\,{x^{2} + t \over 1 + 4t}}\,
\sin\pars{x \over 1 + 4t}\,{2\root{\pi} \over \root{4 + 1/t}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{1 \over \root{4t + 1}}\,\exp\pars{-\,{x^{2} + t \over 1 + 4t}}\,
\sin\pars{x \over 1 + 4t}} \\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I thought the following:

$u(x,t)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-y)^2/4t}\,e^{-y^2}  \sin y  \,dy$

The formula of the solution can be found in the book of Evans, chapter 2. But I do not know how to solve this integral